# Flutter firebase_auth and firebase_core depency errors

Tags: flutter, firebase, flutter-dependencies

I am trying to run my old project after updating flutter sdk to the latest 3.10, but I am getting this error

my pubspec.yaml has the following dependencies

```
dependencies:
  firebase_auth:
  firebase_core:
  intl: ^0.18.1
  flutter_spinkit: ^5.1.0
  web_socket_channel: ^2.0.0
  flutter_native_splash: ^2.2.18
  firebase_database:
  fluttertoast: ^8.0.7
  shared_preferences: ^2.0.8 # Add this line
  url_launcher: ^6.0.0
  http: ^1.0.0
  flutter:
    sdk: flutter

  # The following adds the Cupertino Icons font to your application.
  # Use with the CupertinoIcons class for iOS style icons.
  cupertino_icons: ^1.0.2

dev_dependencies:
  flutter_launcher_icons: ^0.13.1
  flutter_test:
    sdk: flutter

  # The "flutter_lints" package below contains a set of recommended lints to
  # encourage good coding practices. The lint set provided by the package is
  # activated in the `analysis_options.yaml` file located at the root of your
  # package. See that file for information about deactivating specific lint
  # rules and activating additional ones.
  flutter_lints: ^2.0.0

dependency_overrides:
  firebase_core_platform_interface: 4.5.1
```

Running `flutter doctor` shows no issues.

This is the error message I'm getting:

> ../../AppData/Local/Pub/Cache/hosted/pub.dev/firebase_core-2.13.0/lib/src/firebase_app.dart:18:25: Error: Member not found: 'FirebaseAppPlatform.verify'.
>
> ```
> FirebaseAppPlatform.verify(_delegate);
>                     ^^^^^^
> ```
>
> Target kernel_snapshot failed: Exception
>
> FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.
>
> - Where:
>   Script 'C:\src\flutter\packages\flutter_tools\gradle\flutter.gradle' line: 1201
> - What went wrong:
>   Execution failed for task ':app:compileFlutterBuildDebug'.
>   Process 'command 'C:\src\flutter\bin\flutter.bat'' finished with non-zero exit value 1
> - Try:
>   > Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace.
>   > Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
>   > Run with --scan to get full insights.\
> - Get more help at https://help.gradle.org
>
> BUILD FAILED in 40s
> Exception: Gradle task assembleDebug failed with exit code 1

I have tried running flutter upgrade but its not working as well.

Comment: Did you search for the error message yet? I see some promising results here: https://www.google.com/search?q=Member+not+found%3A+%27FirebaseAppPlatform.verify

Comment: Any luck finding the answer to this? I'm seeing the same

Comment: @Mike no luck yet, just opened another recent project and it through the same error

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found a way to fix it

firstly, make sure all dependencies' versions are not specified. Then run
flutter pub get
after this try to run the project and it should through a fullthroughError
after this error has been thrown, open the action_code_info.dart and edit the 'ActionCodeInfo'
it should look something like this
ActionCodeInfoOperation get operation {
switch (_operation) {
case 0:
return ActionCodeInfoOperation.unknown;
case 1:
return ActionCodeInfoOperation.passwordReset;
case 2:
return ActionCodeInfoOperation.verifyEmail;
case 3:
return ActionCodeInfoOperation.recoverEmail;
case 4:
return ActionCodeInfoOperation.emailSignIn;
case 5:
return ActionCodeInfoOperation.verifyAndChangeEmail;
case 6:
return ActionCodeInfoOperation.revertSecondFactorAddition;
default:
throw Exception(); // or throw UnsupportedError('FallThroughError');
}
}

Dart was throwing that error because FallThroughError was not defined, so by editing this file that comes with the package I managed to fix the runtime error and run the code
Hope this really helps someone.